# Проблемы с воспроизведениями анимаций

Tags: unity3d

Есть 2 кнопки стрельбы, нажимая на одну воспроизводится 1 анимация, со 2 аналогично. Нажимая на кнопку меняется анимация.Проблема в том, что bool переменная не обнуляется в аниматоре у 1 анимации. Воспроизведение анимации на клик. Сама проблема на 1 скрине.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private CharacterController ch_controller;
private Animator ch_animator;
private void Start()
{
    ch_controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    ch_animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

public void Gun1()
{


    ch_animator.SetBool("Shooting2", false);


    Debug.Log("A1");
}
public void Gun2()
{

    ch_animator.SetBool("Shooting1", false);
    Debug.Log("b1");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ch_animator.SetBool("Shooting1", false);
ch_animator.SetBool("Shooting2", false);
а в аниматоре Shooting и Shooting2, единицу посеял

Answer (score 0):

Ещё, как вариант, вообще использовать триггеры, а не флаги. Т.е. в аниматоре вместо bool создать триггер. Триггеры - одноразовые флаги, т.е. как только триггер появляется - аниматор его сбрасывает и переходит по тому состоянию, которое для воспроизведения этот триггер использовало.
Ну, это плюсом к тому, что вы либо в аниматоре, либо в скрипте напутали с названием анимации первого выстрела